# LeetCode javascript Palindrome DONE but still getting wrong output

Tags: javascript

```
/**
 * @param {number} x
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isPalindrome = function(x) {
    var y=x,num=0,rem;
    while(x>0)
        {
            rem=x%10;
            num=(num*10)+rem;
            x=x/10;
        }
    if(num==y)
        return true;
    else
        return false ;
};
```

I am still getting wrong output as false but my logic is correct.
This is leetcode palindrome question i am trying it with javascript logic is correct but still not able to figure it out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is asking for debugging help for leetcode work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just one issue:

In JavaScript numbers are floating point numbers by default, and so `/` performs a floating point division. You need to truncate that:

```
    x = Math.floor(x / 10);
```

A remark on your code:

The construct `if (boolean) return true; else false` is an anti-pattern. Since `boolean` already represents the value you want to return, you should just return it. So in your case do:

```
return num == y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems fine but execution is having some minor errors. Please use below snippet, it should work:

```
var isPalindrome = function(x) {
    if (x < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    // Store the number in a variable
    let number = x;
    // This will store the reverse of the number
    let reverse = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        reverse = reverse * 10 + number % 10;
        number = parseInt(number / 10);
    }
    return x === reverse;
}
```

Comment: `parseInt` should be used to convert a string to a number, not to truncate a number.

Comment: Why i should use parseInt as the x is of type number right, so we can do operations directly on the X then why we need to use parseInt please help.